# SpriteKit physicsBody effect lost

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Firstly I added

```
skView.showsPhysics = YES;
```

To see physics body circuit.

**BUT**

I have a problem with loosing physics effect O_o...
I have ball which affected by gravity and falls down.

```
// Ball     
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.size.height/2];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
        self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bottomCategory;
```

Also I've created bottom edged physical body to get collision messages:

```
// Bottom edge 
    CGRect bottomRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y + 25, self.frame.size.width, 10);
        SKNode* bottom = [SKNode node];
        bottom.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:bottomRect];
        [self addChild:bottom];
```

**which correctly interacted with each other before I added bitMask to bottom edge**

```
bottom.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bottomCategory;
bottom.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory;
```

Masks:

```
static const uint32_t ballCategory  = 0x1 << 0;  // 00000000000000000000000000000001
static const uint32_t bottomCategory = 0x1 << 1; // 00000000000000000000000000000010
```

It stopped work. Hm...

I commented out assigning mask to bottom edge - it works.
Then I assigned to bottom edge another - ball mask - it doesn't work again.

I guess, I missed something in documentation but now I can't find answer why it happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bottom.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bottomCategory;
```

This makes `bottom` only contact/collide with bodies whose `contactBitMask` contains the `bottomCategory` bit.

So if you add this category to your balls they should collide with the bottom again:

```
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory | bottomCategory;
```

For more details refer to the [Box2D manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) **Chapter 7.2 - Filtering**.

Comment: 5 minutes back I figured out that I misspelled in my code. By typing contactTestBitMask - I pressed enter when autocomplete appeared, and it turned to collisionBitMask.... brrrr. But, agree with you